# Joining From Differently Formatted Tables

Tags: sql

Table 1:

```
ID   Year   Month
-----------------
1    2018   1
2    2018   1
3    2018   1
1    2018   2
2    2018   2
3    2018   2
```

Table 2:

```
ID  Year  Jan  Feb  Mar
------------------------
1   2018  100  200  300
2   2018  200  400  300
3   2018  200  500  700
```

How can I join these two tables even though they are laid out differently?
I was exploring a case join but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I need.

I'd like my output to be:

```
ID  Year  Month  Data
1   2018  1      100
2   2018  1      200
3   2018  1      200
1   2018  2      200
2   2018  2      400
3   2018  2      500
1   2018  3      300    
2   2018  3      300
3   2018  3      700
```

Comment: UNPIVOT should help.

Comment: An unpivot was indeed the answer. Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, firstly we get TableB in the right format:

```
 SELECT B.ID, B.Year, B.MonthValue 
 INTO TableB_New
 FROM TableB T
 UNPIVOT
 (
    MonthValue FOR Month IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)
 ) AS B
```

And then you do the join. Good Luck!

Comment: An unpivot was indeed the answer. Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it.